# Empty conditional

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following set
$$M_{\delta} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_i\ge1,i=1,\ldots,n,x_j\le 1+\delta , j\in\varnothing\}$$
and I'm not sure how to evaluate it. There is no such $j$ such that the empty set contains it, so is $M_\delta$ empty, or does the condition on $x_j$ just become meaningless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to first rewrite your set condition slightly (it'll make it easier for us in a moment). I find that statements about the empty set are best served looking at them by contrapositive since the logic tends to better align with how we think things should be. The condition is:

> If $x_i\ge 1$ and $x_j \le 1+\delta$ for all $j\in\emptyset$, then $x\in M_{\delta}$.

Taking the contrapositive, this becomes:

> If $x\not\in M_{\delta}$, then either $x_i < 1$ for some $i$ or $x_j > 1+\delta$ for some $j\in\emptyset$.

Since no such $j$ exists, the empty set condition is ineffectual here and can be ignored in your original conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $j$ belongs to the empty set is essentially saying that there are no $j$'s to use for your constraints on $x_j$. So yes, the condition on $x_j$ is meaningless in this case, therefore $M_\delta$ is the just space in $\mathbb R^n$ with each coordinate greater than or equal to $1$.